# Shape object of type msoLine - method to access coordinates of points?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Is there a method for accessing the coordinates of the start and end point of an `msoLine` shape object? I am working with legacy files in Excel 2010 (from Excel 2003 I think).

Given an `msoFreeform` object I can access the various coordinates in turn using something like:

```
  With myDocument.Shapes(i)
     If .Type = msoFreeform Then
       nodeCount = .Nodes.Count
       For k = 1 To nodeCount
         pointsArray = .Nodes.Item(k).Points
         X1 = pointsArray(1, 1)
         Y1 = pointsArray(1, 2)
       Next k
     End If
  End With
```

But this method fails for `msoLine` objects with the `.Nodes.Item(k).Points` returning nothing, even though `.Nodes.Count` returns `2` for a start point and an end point.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
'The "flips" helps to work out which pair of corners of an imaginary rectangle surrounding the line represents the correct diagonal.
```

Sub testLineCoords()

```
Dim bHflip As Boolean
Dim bVflip As Boolean
Dim nBegin As Long
Dim nEnd As Long
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim aC(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Double

Set oShape = ShTmp.Shapes("MyLine")
With oShape
    aC(1, 1) = .Left:           aC(1, 2) = .Top
    aC(2, 1) = .Left + .Width:  aC(2, 2) = .Top
    aC(3, 1) = .Left:           aC(3, 2) = .Top + .Height
    aC(4, 1) = .Left + .Width:  aC(4, 2) = .Top + .Height

    bHflip = .HorizontalFlip
    bVflip = .VerticalFlip
End With

If bHflip = bVflip Then
    If bVflip = False Then
        ' down to right
        nBegin = 1: nEnd = 4
    Else
        ' up to left
        nBegin = 4: nEnd = 1
    End If
ElseIf bHflip = False Then
    ' up to right
    nBegin = 3: nEnd = 2
Else
    ' down to left
    nBegin = 2: nEnd = 3
End If

Debug.Print "---------------------------------"
Debug.Print "Begin X:Y"
Debug.Print aC(nBegin, 1); aC(nBegin, 2)
Debug.Print "End X:Y"
Debug.Print aC(nEnd, 1); aC(nEnd, 2)
```

End Sub

Unfortunately I can't take credit for it:
[Original solution](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=381936)

Regards,
Emiel

Comment: Ah. Of course. Could probably have worked this out if I had inspected the object properties... Thankyou for the answer in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get X/Y starting and ending points for `msoLine` do the followings:

```
Dim myMsoLine As Shape
Set myMsoLine = ActiveSheet.Shapes(3)
Dim X1, X2, Y1, Y2
'points of msoLine

With myMsoLine
    X1 = .Left
    Y1 = .Top
    X2 = .Width + .Left
    Y2 = .Height + .Top
End With

Debug.Print X1, Y1, X2, Y2
```

Generally, there are no nodes in `msoLine` shapes in this situation.
(Tested for Excel 2010)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for confirming that the nodes collection doesn't seem to be accessible for `msoLine` objects. 

I had already considered this approach, but as effectively what is obtained is a bounding box of the line, if the line runs top left to bottom right then the coordinates get mirrored about the centre point of the line such that attempting to recreate the line results in a 'flipped' copy.